# What is the Oxidiser/Fuel Ratio of the Atlas V Centaur Upper Stage?

Tags: fuel, upper-stage, ula, atlas-v, centaur

I can't find this information anywhere for the single or double engine variant. could it be variable? Or is it a secret?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we know the Centaur on [Atlas 5](https://www.ulalaunch.com/rockets/atlas-v) uses RL10C engines, we can [look that up](http://www.rocket.com/rl10-engine).

The current RL10C engine mixture ratio is 5.5.

Comment: According to Spaceflight101, Atlas V Centaurs are now using the RL10-C-1 which is also 5.5:1. http://spaceflight101.com/spacerockets/atlas-v-401/

Comment: Thanks. Confirmed on https://www.ulalaunch.com/rockets/atlas-v

Comment: Oh, sure, like ULA knows anything about it.

Comment: Thanks :) Am I right in thinking the mixture ratio is always Ox/Fuel as an industry standard?

Comment: Yes, the convention is oxidizer mass : fuel mass.

Comment: Various production versions of the RL10 have run anywhere from 5:1 to 6:1, and it's been tested across much broader ranges, even oxidizer-rich (i.e. above the 8:1 stoichiometric ratio). "An amazingly tolerant engine" per Henry Spencer. https://yarchive.net/space/rocket/rl10.html

Comment: ISTR Shuttle Centaur was 6.

Comment: The RL10A-3-3 had a propellant utilization control valve (like the J-2) that could vary the mix ratio between 4.4:1 and 5.6:1 from a nominal 5:1; I haven't been able to confirm that later versions also support variable ratios.